# The process of loading PDF is very slow - iPhone app

Tags: iphone, pdf

in my iPhone application i am loading a pdf file on UIWebview. I PDF URL is called from the webserver. My problem is that it is taking a lot of time to display the PDF File. Can any one please suggest me how can i make it bit fast.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you cannot eliminate the latency in:

- downloading your pdf from the web
- displaying the pdf in the UIWebView

but you *may* be able to *hide* the latency by preparing the data *before* you need to display it in a background operation.   The NSOperationQueue and NSOperation class make doing this relatively straightforward.   Load the data in an NSOperation, save it to a temporary file, assign it to display in a "offscreen" UIWebView (one whose frame makes it not display on the screen), and when you finally need to display the pdf, just place the UIWebView into your current view or move it onscreen by changing its frame.

Comment: Does your PDF file contain many pages and/or high-resolution images?

Comment: @DwightKelly I have the same Issue. PDF contains around 14-15 pages with high-resolution images.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the pdf itself, you can use Acrobat to optimize it for downloading and electronic viewing.

In Acrobat 10, use either the PDF Optimizer command, or the Preflight tool (select Online Publishing 'optimize for size')

Answer (score 0):

Webview is very slow in rendering the PDF. Using native CGPDFDocument API will be fast, but you need to handle the complex loading and rendering process.

Comment: Can you please briefly explain about CGPDFDocument or share some useful link to implement that.